# Keep getting procedure application: expected procedure, from this code

Tags: scheme

Im learning Scheme currently and have been tasked with writing something to count the length of a list, this is the code i currently have.

```
{define (len x) 
    (if(not(null? x))
    (+ 1 len(cdr x))
    (0))}
```

when run with `'(2 3 4 5)` it gives:

```
procedure application: expected procedure, given: '(2 3 4 5) (no arguments)
```

as an error.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As I mentioned in comment on the accepted answer, that doesn't look like an error you would get because of the way your function is defined, but rather from the way you're trying to call it. You need to call it as `(len '(2 3 4 5))`, but I'm guessing you're doing `len('(2 3 4 5))` or `(len('(2 3 4 5)))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have parentheses problems. Try this:

```
(define (len x)
  (if (not (null? x))
      (+ 1 (len (cdr x)))
      0))
```

In particular, notice that:

- When you're going to call a function, the function name (and the parameters, if any) *must* be surrounded by `()`. So `len(x)` is wrong, and `(len x)` is right
- If something is *not* a function, then *don't* surround it with `()`. If you write `(0)`, Scheme believes that `0` is a function and tries to apply it, which clearly is going to fail

Comment: All the issues you pointed out about the code are correct, but I'm not sure where the OP's code would have generated `procedure application: expected procedure, given: '(2 3 4 5) (no arguments)`, unless OP was trying to call it from the REPL like `len('(2 3 4 5))` or `(len('(2 3 4 5)))`.